# Указатели и двумерный массив

Tags: c++, массивы, c, visual-studio

Код:

```
class Forest
{
public:
    char name[255];
    int height, age;
};

int main()
{
    int n = 2;
    Forest **test = new Forest*[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        test[i] = new Forest;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        {
            printf("Wood name: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets((*(*(test+i)+j)).name);
            printf("Wood age: ");
            scanf("%d", &(*(*(test+i)+j)).age);
            printf("Height wood: ");
            scanf("%d", &(*(*(test+i)+j)).height);
            printf("========================\n");
        }
    }
    printf("View data:\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; ++j )
        {
            printf("Wood name: %s\n", test[i][j].name);
            printf("Wood age: %d\n", test[i][j].age);
            printf("Height wood: %d\n", test[i][j].height);
            printf("========================\n");
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        delete test[i];
    delete []test;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

В VS 2010 возникает ошибка: "Обнаружено повреждение кучи".
Как в данном случае правильно обращаться к элементам двумерного массива?

Comment: @Efex, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть два варианта интерпретации вашего кода. Если вы хотите создать двумерный массив объектов типа `Forest`, тогда нужно написать `test[i] = new Forest[2];` ну и соответственно  `delete[] test[i];`. Если же вы хотите создать массив указателей на объект типа `Forest`, тогда нужно убрать все внутренние циклы с `j` и все случаи использования этой переменной — например: `gets((*(*(test+i))).name);`.

Непонятно также, зачем вы используете конструкции вроде `(*(*(test+i)+j)).name`. Неужели нельзя написать `test[i][j].name`? И если вы ввели константу `n`, то в последнем цикле тоже стоит её использовать.

Comment: Можно так написать, но нужно именно через указатель обратиться к элементу массиву.
VS 2010 - отрабатывает с ошибкой
Еще для эксперимента проверил в C++ Builder, там отрабатывает без ошибок, но *.age затирается значением из следующего *.height